# Are HTML and CSS regular languages?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

I have a question whether or not CSS and HTML are regular languages.

I believe CSS is a regular language, since it should be possible to create a regular expression to match the structure of CSS.

However, I believe that HTML is **not** a regular language since you have nested attributes that could be defined recursively.

Comment: [Classic SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/40058).

Comment: An even simpler question than the HTML is [Can regular expressions be used to match nested patterns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns)  The answer is no.  To see that it is simpler, simply translate `(` to `<p>` and `)` to `</p>`.

Comment: However, then an even easier problem is to see if, let's call it "Linear nested parentheses matching", where the input is "$(^n)^n$", i.e., first an arbitrary amount of opening braces followed by the same number of closing braces.  But this is exactly the classical non-regular $\{0^n1^n \mid n \in \omega \}$-language.

Comment: The first rule of CS: abstract. @PålGD does this for you. For the rest, we have our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions).

Comment: By the way, if one is not convinced the above example with `<p>`is allowed, the `<em>` tag allows for arbitrarily deep nesting.

Comment: Nested attributes?

Comment: many thanks to you guys! Helped me to clear my mind ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Providing a regular expression or DFA for a language and proceeding to demonstrate that it is correct for the language in question generally constitutes a pretty convincing argument for the regularity of the language. To prove a language is non-regular, you have a few options: the pumping lemma for regular languages is a classic standby, but the Myhill-Nerode theorem is pretty nifty, too (especially since you can use it to prove regularity as well as non-regularity).

Your first job should be to define what constitute valid strings in the languages $HTML$ and $CSS$. Note that most browsers will take anything you call $HTML$ and display something without error; in that sense, anything is valid $HTML$, and the language $\Sigma^*$ is trivially regular. However, I think it's safe to assume that you have something a bit more strict in mind: $HTML$ consists only of those strings that conform to some standard, which probably calls for matched tags. In this case, you should be able to prove that $HTML$ isn't regular, since you can consider the following kinds of strings (whitespace is added only for clarity and could be removed in the real string):

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <table>
                  ...
               </table>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

This language, `<html><body>` $($ `<table><tr><td>` $)^n($ `</td></tr></table>` $)^n$`</body></html>`, should be enough to get to a proof of non-regularity, provided you accept the above as valid $HTML$, and would say that a missing `</table>` tag would make the resulting string invalid $HTML$, even though browsers would try to render it anyway.

For $CSS$, first figure out what strings you think are valid, then try to come up with a regular expression or DFA for the set of all $CSS$ strings, or figure out how to define a subset of $CSS$ that requires non-local checks and unbounded memory (counting, matching, nesting, etc.) If you can define such a subset (like we did for $HTML$ above), then you're good to go.

Comment: I wonder: in practice, the nesting depth may be bounded by a constant, due to coding standards resp. best practice.

Comment: cool, thanks for that answer! I guess I can build a regex, that can parse CSS, because it follows the same structure, isn't nested, and you have a finite amount of keywords to use. Am I right?

Comment: Note that while the language $\Sigma^*$ is regular, the HTML spec defines how to parse any character stream and that cannot be correctly implemented with a finite state machine (it has a stack of open elements, for a start).